# Signed PDF showing message "The validity of the document is unknown", iText

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I am using iText to apply digital signatures in PDF. The digitally signed PDF is showing message like "the validity of the document certification is unknown. The author could not be verified.At least one signature has problems." at the top.

When I add the certificate to my trust identities which is used to create signed PDF, then the generated signed PDF shows "Signed and all signatures are valid".

Is it possible to fix this by without adding certificate to trusted identities?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not supply a sample PDF to demonstrate that issue. But to trust some certificate you obviously have to explicitly trust it or some parent, greatparent, ... certificate of it and supply the intermediate certificates. Is the signer certificate in question self signed or does it belong to some private CA?

Comment: Instead of manually trusting the certificate, it should automatically trust and it should not show the validity error.    The signer certificate is obtained from verisign Inc.

Comment: As mentioned above, phrase supply a sample PDF.

Comment: BTW, you expect the signature to be immediately accepted by Adobe Reader because "The signer certificate is obtained from verisign Inc." --- It does not suffice to use a certificate by Verisign, it has to be one which explicitly is generated for use with Adobe Reader. Thus, please supply a sample signature (or the certificate in question, *not the private key*!) to allow a check.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons for the message to be displayed.

First, it's that you used self-signed certificate or other certificate, whose certificate chain doesn't end with the root certificate, trusted by validating application.

Second is when the signature parameters are not set right and Reader doesn't know that it needs to look for certificates in Windows certificate store. I don't know how to specify what I mean in iText - in our SecureBlackbox there's a property for this.

Comment: Actually iText is not the program displaying that message; iText does not itself offer a UI. I assume the component displaying that message is Adobe Reader. 'Orn do you mean parameters in the signature creating component?

Comment: @mkl yes, type of storage to use during validation is in fact specified when the signature is created. Here's an article in our FAQ that describes details: http://www.eldos.com/security/articles/2992.php

Comment: Having googled around a bit it looks like that was strictly enforced up to Adobe Acrobat/Reader version 6 only. I have not tested that, though. But if missing intermediate certificates really are the problem, the original poster had better consider embedding the whole certificate chain. This would help not only the Adobe program versions for Windows in question but actually any decent verification tool. Unfortunately he has not yet supplied a sample signature to inspect...

Answer (score 2):

Please read https://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

Section 3.4 is named "How to get a green check mark."

The short version: if you want a PDF that shows a green check mark without having to install a root certificate manually, you need at least a private key that is stored on a physical device such as a Hardware Security Module, a USB token or a smart card.

Do you have such a key? Did you ask your CA for CDS or AATL certificate?

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

Yes, I am trying to use the CDS certificate provided by GlobalSign.
 
Tried instructions in the following URL:
https://www.globalsign.com/resources/installation-guide/pdf-signing-installation-guide.pdf

Comment: My situation is, The users will sign the documents from anywhere. 
The signed PDFs are generated at the server side using iText and CDS certificate obtained from CA.


In this scenario, 

1. which one i need to use whether USB token/HSM?

2. I red in the following article that 
If i use USB token(SafeNet iKey4000) to create digital signature, whether it will ask for password everytime when the signing takes place?

In page number 88, http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures20121017.pdf

Please advise on this.

Comment: If users have to sign from everywhere in their own name, they all need their own USB token containing their own private key. In this case, pure server-side signing is impossible. You'll always need software on the client-side that uses the personal private key of the signer. It is impossible (and it would be absurd) to send the private key to the server.

Comment: If you want pure server-side signing, you need an HSM on the server. This HSM will contain YOUR private key, so when users sign on your server, you will sign on their behalf using your certificate. Your users will have no responsibility whatsoever. YOU will be responsible for that signature. In short: you need to read the white paper once more, because I think you're missing something that is essential.

Comment: Hmm the users will not sign the documents by their own names. On behalf of users we will sign the document by company name. Is it right have a USB token in server and create digital signature using the private key stored in the USB token?

Comment: You can do that, but as opposed to using a Hardware Security Module, you'll have to take into account that you can't sign more than one document a second using an USB token. USB tokens are meant for personal use; HSMs for automated use.

Answer (score 1):

Re: Is it possible to fix this by without adding certificate to trusted identities?

**Answer: no**, unless you switch to a digital signature cert that was granted by a Certificate Authority trusted by Adobe.

This is an on-going issue with Adobe since Adobe Reader doesn't trust the CA's in the operating system. -- Instead, Adobe has [their own list](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list1.html).

So either:

1. You get a personal cert from one of the companies on the Adobe list.
2. You publish your organization's root certificate on your website and provide instructions to recipients on how to tell Adobe to trust you. (Your organization can have just one member if you wish.) See below for more on this.
3. You tell your recipients how to click on the Adobe signature toolbar to inspect the details of the signing cert (and ignore the scary default warnings from Adobe).

**In the wet-signature world**, there are cases where you simply sign something, and other cases where you need to provide a copy of your government issued identity document. Unfortunately, in the current digital signature world, it's as if *every* signature needs to be accompanied by a copy of your driver's license. And that is simply not reality.

A common and successful answer is to publish your organization's root cert for all of the organization's signers. See [Apple](http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) and [Wells Fargo](https://www.wellsfargo.com/com/cps) examples.

You can publish your root cert on an SSL-protected page with a cert from a trusted CA. That will enable a business partner to feel secure about trusting that your org's root cert is really from your org.

Comment: hi, i have ssl files private.key, CA.cer and company.cer (contains 3 blocks our company details,RapidSSL RSA CA 2018, DigiCert Global Root CA), using this command `openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey private.key -in company.cer -certfile CA.cer ` converted to pfx and using portablesigner i have signed a PDF file, but in adobe its still showing author could not be verified, even i've updated adobe latest trusted certificates

Comment: Hi, Please ask your question as a NEW question on stack overflow.

Comment: hi, you've mentioned that Adobe have ownlist of trusted companies, yes the ssl  which i used for signing pdf is trusted by adobe, digicert is there in their list.but still its showing that message