# How to check the genuineness of a PDF file

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, adobe, adobe-reader

I want to know the method that Adobe apply to check the genuineness of a PDF file.
I mean, did Adobe keep any kind of signature or parameter or Attribute while creating PDF file , which can be use for verification.
there must be some way to do this.

Comment: And because you tag the question with itext, the assumption is that you want to do that check with iText, right?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "genuine"? I can take your PDF, copy the values I want and change others, place those into a brand new PDF and my PDF will be "genuine". A "genuine" copy, true, but "genuine" nonetheless.

Comment: See [Digital Signatures: how it's done in PDF](http://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/digital-signatures-how-its-done-in-pdf-46029889) and read [this free ebook](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html).

Comment: I've closed the question by referring to a question that has the answer to your question. In that answer, you'll find a list of all the operations that are allowed after signing a document. You will also benefit from the answer to the question [Certifying Pdf document with iText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990757/)